# pure javascript tabs no jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i create a multiple tabs like i have one select box ,i want to fire function on onchange  by which i want to display div if they match option value,if option value is 1 i want div with id 1 to get displayed and rest hide.
code would b like

```
<select id="sel" onChange="valueNew()">
    <option> 1 </option>
    <option> 2 </option>
    <option> 3 </option>
</select>

<div style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px; display:none"></div>
<div style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none"></div>
<div style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none"></div>
```

Comment: You need the [Change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) and to amend the [Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) of the elements.

Comment: @Deepak Sabharwal where are `div ids` in you html ? I don't see any.

Comment: i have just given sample code it would be like
<option value="1"></option>
<div id="1"></div> or any better organisation ..sorry for bad code written m unable to paste code in format

Comment: Give the elements an id, set the value to the same id, onchange get the id, hide the other divs, and  set the display to block of the current id.

Comment: guys dont give me negative feedback i am unable to put code in format on stack overflow i am new here

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
// get all div with class name 'div'
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
function valueNew(ele) {
  // iterating over all div and hidding all
  for (var i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    div[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
  // getting div which is need to show using value of selected option
  div[ele.value].style.display = 'block';
}

// trigger change event to show default div
document.getElementById('sel').onchange();
```

```html
<select id="sel" onChange="valueNew(this)">
  <option value="0">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="2">3</option>
</select>

<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px; display:none">1</div>
<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">2</div>
<div class="div" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">3</div>
```

Comment: I'm judging by the title that the OP specifically doesn't want a jQuery implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
function valueNew() {
    for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("div").length; i++) {
        (document.querySelectorAll("div")[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
    document.querySelectorAll("div")[document.querySelector("#sel").value - 1].style.display = "block";

}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/72k57dc4/)

Answer (score 0):

Find the following example:

```js
function changeTab(value)
{
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
  
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<tabs.length; i++)
    {
        tabs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  
    document.getElementById("tab_" + value).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<select id="sel" onChange="changeTab(this.value)">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>

<div class="tabs" id="tab_1" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px; display:none">First Tab</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab_2"  style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">Second Tab</div>
<div class="tabs" id="tab_3" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none">Third Tab</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like:

```
'use strict';

function Tabs() {
  var bindAll = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuElements.length ; i++) {
      menuElements[i].addEventListener('click', change, false);
    }
  }

  var clear = function() {
    var menuElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab]');
    for(var i = 0; i < menuElements.length ; i++) {
      menuElements[i].classList.remove('active');
      var id = menuElements[i].getAttribute('data-tab');
      document.getElementById(id).classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  var change = function(e) {
    clear();
    e.target.classList.add('active');
    var id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-tab');
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('active');
  }

  bindAll();
}

var connectTabs = new Tabs();
```

http://codepen.io/wangel13/pen/OXBrRp

And code:

https://github.com/WaNgeL-SaTaR/pure-js-tab

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="sel" onChange="valueNew()">
    <option value="one"> 1 </option>
    <option value="two"> 2 </option>
    <option value="three"> 3 </option>
</select>

<div id="one" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;      display:none"></div>
<div id="two" style="background:#ddd;width:100%;  height:500px;display:none"></div>
<div id="three" style="background:#ddd;width:100%; height:500px;display:none"></div>
```

I have done a couple of changes in your HTML. You can easily identify it. Now for the JS part.

```
function valueNew(){    
var x = document.getElementById("sel");
for(var i=0; i< x.options.length;i++){
if(x.value === x.options[i].value){
document.getElementById(x.options[i].value).style.display="block";
}
else
{
document.getElementById(x.options[i].value).style.display="none";
}
}   
}
```